# Creating a custom directive that uses extractCredentials directive - value map is not a member calling extractCredentials

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I want to create a custom directive that will wrap some Routes, which will then give the inner routes access to the UserContext object (if it exists).

```
authenticated { uc =>
  post {
       // ... can use uc object here
  }
}
```

I am getting a compile time error with the below code:

```
case class UserContext(username: String)

def authenticated: Directive1[Option[UserContext]] =
    for {
      credentials <- extractCredentials
      result <- {
        credentials match {
          case Some(c) if c.scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer") => UserContext(c.token()) // authenticate(c.token)
          case _ => None  //rejectUnauthenticated(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsMissing)
        }
      }
    } yield result
```

The error is:

```
 value map is not a member of UserRoutes.this.UserContext
[error]         credentials match {
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I am using VS Code with bloop, and the mouseover error says:

> value map is not a member of Product with java.io.Serializable

extractCredentials returns an Option[HttpCredentials] so I'm not sure why I can't match on it or map on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the error of the **Product with Serializable**, you are trying to create a Directive. If you fix your code with Some(UserContext) the next error is:

```
Error:(113, 14) type mismatch;
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive
```

The compiler says that when you do a flatMap to a Directive you need to return a new Directive and not an Option.

At this point you can create a Directive from a function ***(Tuple1(Option[User) => Route) => Route***. Considering that a Route is a ***RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]*** like:

```
def authenticated: Directive1[Option[UserContext]] = {
  extractCredentials.flatMap { credentials =>
      Directive { inner =>
        ctx => {
          val result = credentials match {
            case Some(c) if c.scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer") => Some(UserContext(c.token())) // authenticate(c.token)
            case _ => None //rejectUnauthenticated(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsMissing)
          }
          inner(Tuple1(result))(ctx)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With this you have a new directive ***authenticated*** that uses extractCredentials.

Answer (score 1):

What you do here:

```
  case Some(c) if c.scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer") => UserContext(c.token()) // authenticate(c.token)
  case _ => None  //rejectUnauthenticated(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsMissing)
```

is returning either `UserContext` or `None`. Some compiler has to infer a common type between these two. Each `case class` or `case object` implement `Product with Serializable` so it will be a LUB of each two `case` instances that don't implement other common shared supertype.

So what is on right side of `result` will be inferred to be `Product with Serializable` instead of `Option[UserContext]`. `for` comprehension expects that there is `Option` with a `map`, on which it could call `.map { result => result }` and as we see the types aren't matching.

Is believe you wanted to have here

```
  case Some(c) if c.scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer") => Some(UserContext(c.token()))
  case _ => None
```

Just in case, reminder: `Option` is not the same as `@nullable` in Java, so `a: A` is not automatically promoted to `Some(a): Option[A]` and `None` is different to `null`.

EDIT:

The other thing is that you have flatMap and map on 2 different types (Directive and Option) so you cannot just combine both of them in one for comprehension. I assume you wanted to do something like:

```
extractCredentials.map { credentials =>
  credentials.collect {
    case c if c.scheme.equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer") => UserContext(c.token())
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting a type mismatch saying:  ```found   : Option[UserRoutes.this.UserContext]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(Option[UserRoutes.this.UserContext],)]